# MATLAB rand(m,n)

Tags: random-variables, matlab

I want reconfirm what I believe is the answer. So this is the question: "Make a vector in MATLAB with $n = 10$ random elements, and then ﬁnd the percentage of those
elements that are less than $\frac{1}{2}$."

Here is my code:

```
n = 10;
a = rand(1, n);
b = a<1/2; 
disp(sum(b)*100/n)
```

Every time I run the script, I would get a different answer, i.e. $40$ then $70$ then $40$ again, etc. Now I believe the code is right but the outputs are different because it is taking the percentage of $10$ random elements hence the answer will continue outputting different answers. But the solution, states that it was $30$% which confused me and don't know whether that is the definite solution or it is one of many possible solutions. Thanks !!!!

Comment: Is the number of elements of an array sum(b) in Matlab?

Comment: What I miss here, is that it should be "uniformly distributed " random elements. That's what rand() function does. Also be aware that it is advisable to initialize the random seed (otherwise it may happen that you get the same outputs if repeated). See http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: A bit shorter would be to have the last line disp(mean(b)*100)

Comment: Each time the script is run a different (pseudo)random sample is constructed. So yes, you will get a different answer each time. There is no "correct" answer. there is only correct code. Your code is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is correct.

Since there are only 10 numbers you will always get one of 0%, 10%, 20%, ...., 90%, 100%.

The answer "30%" is only an example of a possible outcome.

Since the output is based on data randomly generated it is normal it's not exactly equal to what you get.